# Change ACF Select field Dynamically Based on Repeater Field values for every custom post

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, acfpro

I have two a repeater field inside a group field and a select field. What I'm trying to do is get strings from repeater field to select field dynamically for every custom post. I tried ACF codex code but when I try to edit these post type's pages, it returns with 503 service error.

**My functions.php Code**

```
function select_my_field( $field ) {

    global $post;

    if( have_rows('dies_and_hand_tools_product', $post->ID) ): while ( have_rows('dies_and_hand_tools_product', $post->ID) ) : the_row(); 


        if( have_rows('applicable_products', $post->ID) ): while ( have_rows('applicable_products', $post->ID) ) : the_row(); 

                $choices[get_sub_field('applicable_product_name')] = get_sub_field('applicable_product_name');

            endwhile; endif;
    
    endwhile; endif;
    
    $field['choices'] = $choices;            

    return $field;
}

add_filter( 'acf/load_field/key=field_5ffc592f83066', 'select_my_field' );
```

**what I'am trying to reach**

dies_and_hand_tools_product(Group) -> applicable_products(Repeater) -> applicable_product_name(text)

**What I'am trying to change**

dies_and_hand_tools_product(Group) -> dh_product_table(Group) -> applicable_with(select)(key: field_5ffc592f83066)

[image: What fields look like]